# Python's descriptor "__get__" was not called as I expected, reason?

Tags: python, class, get, descriptor, owner

I was trying python's descriptor of **get**, to see if it's called.

I've got the following:

```
"""This is the help document"""
class c1(object):
    """This is my __doc__"""
    def __get__(s,inst,owner):
      print "__get__"

    def __init__(s):
      print "__init__"
      s.name='abc'

class d(object):
    def __init__(s):
    s.c=c1()

d1=d()
d1.c
print d1.c.name
```

I expect that it will call **get** function. But it fact the output is

```
__init__
abc
```

Why my "**get**" function was not called by instance owner of "d1"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descriptors must be bound to a class, not an instance.

```
class d(object):
  c = c1()
```